# How to display "12 minutes ago" etc in a PHP webpage?

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how I can display a status message like "12 seconds ago" or "5 minutes ago" etc in a web page?

Comment: This has been covered (though with more of a C# focus) in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time).

Comment: This question was [previously asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time), the example code in answers should be pretty easy to convert to PHP.

Comment: There is a nice jquery plugin : timeago.js

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here is the php code for the same:

```
function time_since($since) {
    $chunks = array(
        array(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 , 'year'),
        array(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 , 'month'),
        array(60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 'week'),
        array(60 * 60 * 24 , 'day'),
        array(60 * 60 , 'hour'),
        array(60 , 'minute'),
        array(1 , 'second')
    );

    for ($i = 0, $j = count($chunks); $i < $j; $i++) {
        $seconds = $chunks[$i][0];
        $name = $chunks[$i][1];
        if (($count = floor($since / $seconds)) != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $print = ($count == 1) ? '1 '.$name : "$count {$name}s";
    return $print;
}
```

The function takes the number of seconds as input and outputs text such as:

- 10 seconds
- 1 minute

etc

Comment: Oh and don't forget to change those multiplications with the real values, so that it won't be calculated every time it runs :)

Comment: Since I was curious, replacing the multiplication sequences with the evaluated products was ~1.2% faster.

Comment: It only shows `33 minutes` no matter what I changing the date and time too

Comment: @ErikEdgren I had same problem because I was sending date instead of seconds. Try this: `time_since(time() - strtotime($datetime))`

Comment: TWEAK WITH JUST NOW.   function time_since($since) {
 $chunks = array( array(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 , 'year'), array(60 * 60 * 24 * 30 , 'month'), array(60 * 60 * 24 * 7, 'week'),array(60 * 60 * 24 , 'day'),array(60 * 60 , 'hour'),array(60 , 'minute'),array(1, 'sec'));

 for ($i = 0, $j = count($chunks); $i < $j; $i++) {
  $seconds = $chunks[$i][0];
  $name = $chunks[$i][1]; $count = floor($since / $seconds); if ($count != 0) {break;}
 } if( $count == 1){  return $print = '1 '.$name;} else if($count  < 1) {  return $print = 'just now'; } else { return $print = "$count {$name}s" ;} }

Answer (score 16):

```
function timeAgo($timestamp){
    $datetime1=new DateTime("now");
    $datetime2=date_create($timestamp);
    $diff=date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    $timemsg='';
    if($diff->y > 0){
        $timemsg = $diff->y .' year'. ($diff->y > 1?"'s":'');

    }
    else if($diff->m > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->m . ' month'. ($diff->m > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->d > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->d .' day'. ($diff->d > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->h > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->h .' hour'.($diff->h > 1 ? "'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->i > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->i .' minute'. ($diff->i > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->s > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->s .' second'. ($diff->s > 1?"'s":'');
    }

$timemsg = $timemsg.' ago';
return $timemsg;
}
```

Comment: I used a modified version of this, I replaced the date_create line with    $datetime2 =  new DateTime();
$datetime2->setTimestamp($timestamp);
and removed all the apostrophes before the s string

Answer (score 6):

PHP's `\DateTime::diff` returns a [`\DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/dateInterval) object on which you can get the minutes by the public `i` property.