# Relative Time with GetText

Tags: php, time, gettext

i'm working on a multilanguage application with php5 and gettext.

Rightnow i would like to show a relative time but i've got some problems with it, while keeping the multilanguage.

I tried google to google for a solution but could not find a proper way to do it and could not get the changes to work on my own.

I hope you've got a solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean with relative time?

Comment: Probably "5 minutes ago", etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685/how-to-display-12-minutes-ago-etc-in-a-php-webpage Would you care to explain what problem you are having?

Comment: One common way is `printf(_('%d seconds ago'), $seconds)`.  That way, the translations just need to know to have the conversion specification present without caring about the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function getRelativeTime($date) {
    $diff = time() - strtotime($date);
    if ($diff<60)
        return strtr(ngettext("vor einer Sekunde", "vor %time% Sekunden", $diff), array("%time%" => $diff));
    $diff = round($diff/60);
    if ($diff<60)
        return strtr(ngettext("vor einer Minute", "vor %time% Minuten", $diff), array("%time%" => $diff));
    $diff = round($diff/60);
    if ($diff<24)
        return strtr(ngettext("vor einer Stunde", "vor %time% Stunden", $diff), array("%time%" => $diff));
    $diff = round($diff/24);
    if ($diff<7)
        return strtr(ngettext("vor einem Tag", "vor %time% Tagen", $diff), array("%time%" => $diff));
    $diff = round($diff/7);
    if ($diff<4)
        return strtr(ngettext("vor einer Woche", "vor %time% Wochen", $diff), array("%time%" => $diff));
    $diff = round($diff/4);
    if ($diff<12)
        return strtr(ngettext("vor einem Monat", "vor %time% Monaten", $diff), array("%time%" => $diff));
    return strtr(_("am %date% um %time%"), array("%time%" => strftime('%X', strtotime($date)),
                                                 "%date%" => strftime('%x', strtotime($date))
                                                 ));
}

?>
```

This is my solution.

Comment: Could add a little bit more information, because it's kinda "hard" to understand your could, by simply reading it.
Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using a client-side implementation, you might want to check out http://timeago.yarp.com/
It takes off server side load, provides better options for caching, and has multilingual support.